# StringContainsQ And

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm looking to test whether a string contains all substrings in it, independent of each substrings location.
For example:

```
StringContainsQ[{"abcd", "cdab", "acdb", "abdc"}, "ab" ~~ ___ ~~ "cd"]
```

Results in:

```
{True, False, False, False}
```

But what I'm looking for would be:

```
{True, True, False, False}
```

However, something like:

```
StringContainsQ[{"abcd", "cdab", "acdb", "abdc"}, "ab"&&"cd"]
```

Results in errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
StringContainsQ[{"abcd", "cdab", "acdb", "abdc"},
   ("ab" ~~ ___ ~~ "cd")|( "cd" ~~ ___ ~~ "ab")]
```

> {True, True, False, False}

Also

```
And @@@ Transpose[StringContainsQ[{"abcd", "cdab", "acdb", "abdc"}, #]&/@ {"ab", "cd"}]
```

> {True, True, False, False}

```
And @@@ Outer[StringContainsQ,{"abcd", "cdab", "acdb", "abdc"}, {"ab","cd"}]
```

> {True, True, False, False}

Comment: The first method only works if there cannot be any overlap in the substrings.

Answer (score 6):

```
StringContainsQ[{"abcd", "cdab", "acdb", "abdc"}, RegularExpression["(?=.*ab)(?=.*cd)"]]
```

> {True, True, False, False}

(See [Achieving logical “and” with Look-aheads](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/) (ie in regular expressions)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/470602/499167) SO answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
strings = {"fcdeab", "abcdef", "cdefab", "acfdbe", "efabdc"};
joins = StringJoin /@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Map[Characters, strings];
{"ab", "cd"} == Intersection[#, {"ab", "cd"}] & /@ joins
```

> {True, True, True, False, False}